Warning from ActiveMQ Artemis running in Docker
I have configured the following docker-compose to start a simple instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.33 with Docker Desktop on Windows 11. The broker is working fine, and from my local machine, I have an application that consumes and sends messages to the Artemis broker correctly.
The new thing I have noticed is that when my application sends messages, the following WARNING is logged in the container, which does not cause an error since the message reaches the broker.
2024-04-16 10:03:17 2024-04-16 15:03:17,298 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.25.0.1:55136 has been detected: null [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]

It is important to mention that the IP 172.25.0.1 is that of the Gateway inside the container, as indicated in the following image:

Can you help me identify why this behavior is happening? Currently, these WARNINGS are being logged in the Artemis log, but my concern is why and how I can prevent them from being generated.
Thank you in advance for your help

The AMQ212037 warning message(s) indicate that an application is not properly closing its connection(s) to the broker. Please ensure all your applications are handling their resources properly and especially not exiting before closing their connection(s).
